# Output custom function result in xslt template with UMI CMS

Tags: php, templates, xslt

I made my custom function in modules/custom.php file, and I'm trying to output its result into xslt template with the following line

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('udata://custom/gettimedata/')/udata" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

It works if I put this line into xslt/blocks/footer.xsl file. But it doesn't if I put this into xslt/layouts/default.xsl
How do I pass result of my custom function into default template? Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my way to fix this was to enable debug mode in config.ini which located in site root directory, which gave me an error output with message that my function provides data not encoded in utf-8. When I fixed encoding to utf-8 I got a proper template output.